# Create a simple "scheme" environment and a "List of Schemes"

Tags: environments, subcaption, chemistry

I have the majority of my thesis written and typeset. Currently, I have a List of Figures and a List of Tables.

**However, now my committee tells me that I must also have a List of Schemes.** In chemistry, a scheme is an environment that contains (images of) chemical structures and reactions.

Unfortunately, I have already coded my chemical structures as figures.  There are a few packages, such as [`chemstyle`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemstyle?lang=en) and [`chemscheme`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemscheme?lang=en), that appear to provide their own scheme constructs.  However, I would prefer not to use them since some of those packages set their own defaults for things like chemical formulas.  (For example, I see that the [`chemstyle`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemstyle?lang=en) package defines `\ie`, but I already have my own definition for `\ie` in my thesis.)  I am already using the [`chemformula`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemformula?lang=en) and [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en) packages.

**Is there any way I can more simply create my own Scheme environment?  The only difference I need is that schemes should be captioned as "Scheme" and listed in a List of Schemes.  In other words, the only difference between a figure and a scheme is in bookkeeping.**

Here is my MWE, with several of the crucial packages that I'm using.  One possible complication is that I use the [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=en) package to create subfigures.  Typically I have only one image per figure/scheme, but I create sub references using `\phantomsubcaption` from the [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=en) package.  Also, I am using the [`tocloft`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) package to adjust spacings in the lists of figures and tables, and that could potentially complicate things further.

Finally, it would be nice if I could use the new "scheme" environment with the [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en) package, since I use the `\cref` command from that package a lot to refer to figures, tables, etc.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  barriers/use, barriers/reset,
  use-id-as-short,
}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.g.}
\newcommand{\cf}{cf.}
\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{charge-hshift=.5pt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.9em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.9em}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

% \phantomsection %% Remove if using hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\chapter{First chapter}
Text in the first chapter.
Refer to \cref{fig:firstfig} using cleveref package.
Refer to \cref{tbl:firsttbl}.
Refer to \cref{fig:multi}, \cref{fig:multi:a}, and \cref{fig:multi:b}.
Refer to eventual scheme, \cref{scm:eventualscheme}.
Refer to eventual multi-part scheme, \cref{scm:eventualmultischeme}.
% Example figure
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Caption of figure in first chapter.}\label{fig:firstfig}
\end{figure}

% Example table 
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    A & B\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption of table in first chapter.}\label{tbl:firsttbl}
\end{table}

% MULTIPART FIGURE 
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:multi:a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0pt}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:multi:b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption of figure referring to parts \subref{fig:multi:a} and \subref{fig:multi:b} with subref command.}\label{fig:multi}
\end{figure}

% I NEED TO CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIGURE TO A SCHEME (SINGLE-PART SCHEME)
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption of eventual scheme.}\label{scm:eventualscheme}
\end{figure}

% I NEED TO CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIGURE TO A SCHEME (MULTI-PART SCHEME, BUT ONLY WITH ONE IMAGE)
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{scm:eventualmultischeme:a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0pt}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{scm:eventualmultischeme:a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption of eventual scheme referring to parts \subref{fig:multi:a} and \subref{fig:multi:b} with subref command.}\label{scm:eventualmultischeme}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second chapter}
Text in the second chapter.
Refer to \cref{fig:secondfig}.
% Another example figure
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Caption of figure in second chapter.}\label{fig:secondfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Are you aware that `chemmacros` already offers its own `scheme` environment including `cleveref` support?

Comment: @leandriis Ummmmm, no... sorry, I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can combine `chemmacros`' `scheme` module with `subcaption` and `cleveref`.

- List of Schemes:

[image]

- References to schemes and subschemes:

[image]

- Captions of schemes:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  barriers/use, barriers/reset,
  use-id-as-short,
}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.g.}
\newcommand{\cf}{cf.}
\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{charge-hshift=.5pt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=scheme}

\AtEndPreamble{\DeclareCaptionSubType*{scheme}}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.9em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.9em}


\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefformat{subscheme}{\schemename~#2#1#3}


\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

% \phantomsection %% Remove if using hyperref
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listschemename}
\listofschemes

\chapter{First chapter}
Text in the first chapter.

Refer to \cref{fig:firstfig} using cleveref package.

Refer to \cref{tbl:firsttbl}.

Refer to \cref{fig:multi}, \cref{fig:multi:a}, and \cref{fig:multi:b}.

Refer to eventual scheme, \cref{scm:eventualscheme}.

Refer to eventual multi-part scheme, \cref{scm:eventualmultischeme}, \cref{scm:eventualmultischeme:a}, and \cref{scm:eventualmultischeme:b}.


\begin{figure}[!h]
  \caption{Caption of figure in first chapter.}\label{fig:firstfig}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{Caption of table in first chapter.}\label{tbl:firsttbl}
\end{table}

 
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:multi:a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0pt}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:multi:b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption of figure referring to parts \subref{fig:multi:a} and \subref{fig:multi:b} with subref command.}\label{fig:multi}
\end{figure}


\begin{scheme}[!h]
  \caption{Caption of scheme.}\label{scm:eventualscheme}
\end{scheme}

\begin{scheme}[!h]

  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{scm:eventualmultischeme:a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0pt}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{scm:eventualmultischeme:b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption of scheme referring to parts \subref{fig:multi:a} and \subref{fig:multi:b} with subref command.}\label{scm:eventualmultischeme}
\end{scheme}

\chapter{Second chapter}
Text in the second chapter.
Refer to \cref{fig:secondfig}.

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \caption{Caption of figure in second chapter.}\label{fig:secondfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{scheme}[!h]
  \caption{Caption of scheme.}\label{scm:eventualscheme2}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

---

Side note: Prior to version 5.11a (2020-11-21) `chemmacros` `\listofschemes` was incompatible with the `book` class. (See also: [corresponding bug report](https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/issues/41)) If the above solution does not work for you, consider updating to version `5.11a` or newer.

To keep this answer short, I have removed the MWE that used version 5.11 and in which I showed how to overcome some formatting inconsistencies between the list of schemes and the list of figures.

Comment: I could not get this to compile on overleaf. It will compile with warnings if  `\listofschemes` is disabled, Still the schemes do not show the chapter number.

Comment: Which warning/error messages exactly do you get?

Comment: without `\listofschemes` it gives a `chemmacros` warning which I dont mind. The issue is the fact that chapter numbers do not appear in schemes, They are labeled 1,2,3,... instead of 1.1, 1.2(a), 1.2(b), 2.1...

Comment: Which version of the `chemmacros` package is used by overleaf? There was a related bug and from your description, I guess the behaviour you observe may also be caused by this bug. The code in my answer only works correctly with version 5.11a or newer.

Comment: i believe overleaf loads chemmacros v5.11 (2020/03/07). Isn't that newer than 5.11a? Here is a link to the overleaf project https://www.overleaf.com/9366523359fmyvvdqqdbzy

Comment: @KuraviH: No, version 5.11a is definitely newer than version 5.11. If I remember correctly, you can use a newer version of a package in overleaf if you add the corresponding .sty file (e.g. from CTAN) to your project directory.

Answer (score 3):

Load the `newfloat` package and the `scheme` module for `chemmacros`.

You just have to set up a `subscheme` environment for `subcaption`, which has to be done at begin document.

I loaded `tocbibind` for adding `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` to the table of contents. Your manual method is incorrect: you should at least have `\cleardoublepage` before `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref} % should be last

% acro options
\acsetup{
  barriers/use, barriers/reset,
  use-id-as-short,
}
% chemmacros options
\usechemmodule{scheme}
% chemformula options
\setchemformula{charge-hshift=.5pt}
% tocloft options
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.9em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.9em}
% caption options
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareCaptionSubType*[alph]{scheme}}

% personal commands
\newcommand{\ie}{i.e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.g.}
\newcommand{\cf}{cf.}
\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\overline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofschemes

\chapter{First chapter}

Text in the first chapter.
Refer to \cref{fig:firstfig} using cleveref package.
Refer to \cref{tbl:firsttbl}.
Refer to \cref{fig:multi}, \cref{fig:multi:a}, and \cref{fig:multi:b}.
Refer to eventual scheme, \cref{scm:eventualscheme}.
Refer to eventual multi-part scheme, \cref{scm:eventualmultischeme}.

% Example figure
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Caption of figure in first chapter.}\label{fig:firstfig}
\end{figure}

% Example table 
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    A & B\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption of table in first chapter.}\label{tbl:firsttbl}
\end{table}

% MULTIPART FIGURE 
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:multi:a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:multi:b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption of figure referring to parts \subref{fig:multi:a} and \subref{fig:multi:b} with subref command.}\label{fig:multi}
\end{figure}

\begin{scheme}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption of eventual scheme.}\label{scm:eventualscheme}
\end{scheme}

\begin{scheme}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subscheme}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{scm:eventualmultischeme:a}
  \end{subscheme}
  \begin{subscheme}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{scm:eventualmultischeme:b}
  \end{subscheme}
  \caption{Caption of eventual scheme referring to parts \subref{fig:multi:a} and \subref{fig:multi:b} with subref command.}\label{scm:eventualmultischeme}
\end{scheme}

\chapter{Second chapter}

Text in the second chapter.
Refer to \cref{fig:secondfig}.

% Another example figure
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Caption of figure in second chapter.}\label{fig:secondfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @leandriis noted in the comments, the `chemmacros` package apparently already does what you want.

Otherwise, you just have to add the lines

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=los,placement={!ht},name=Scheme]{myscheme}
\captionsetup[myscheme]{labelfont=bf}
\crefname{myscheme}{scheme}{schemes}
```

to your preamble and then can use a new float type `myscheme` similar to `figures`. The list of schemes is produces with `\listofmyschemes`.