# Why are my schemes being numbered starting at 0?

Tags: subcaption, cleveref, chemmacros

I am trying to apply [leandriis's excellent recipe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571884/15622) for generating the subschemes using the [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en), [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en), and [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=en) packages.

In the following example, what am I doing wrong?  The schemes are numbered starting at 0, but I want them to start at 1.  I'm sure my mistake is obvious, but I just don't see it.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  barriers/use, barriers/reset,
  use-id-as-short,
}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{charge-hshift=.5pt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{scheme}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.9em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.9em}

\AtEndPreamble{\DeclareCaptionSubType*{scheme}\counterwithin{scheme}{chapter}\renewcommand\thesubscheme{\thescheme\alph{subscheme}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{los}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefformat{subscheme}{\schemename~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listschemename}
\listofschemes

% Example figure
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Caption of figure in first chapter.}\label{fig:firstfig}
\end{figure}

% Example subfigure
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:secondfig:a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:secondfig:b}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Caption of second figure.
  Part \subref{fig:secondfig:a} and part \subref{fig:secondfig:b}.}\label{fig:secondfig}
\end{figure}

% Example scheme
\begin{scheme}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption of first scheme.}\label{sch:firstscheme}
\end{scheme}

% Example subscheme
\begin{scheme}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subscheme}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{sch:thirdscheme:a}
  \end{subscheme}%
  \begin{subscheme}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{sch:thirdscheme:b}
  \end{subscheme}%
  \caption{Caption of third scheme.
  Part \subref{sch:thirdscheme:a} and part \subref{sch:thirdscheme:a}.}\label{sch:thirdscheme}
\end{scheme}

Refer to \cref{fig:firstfig} using cleveref package.
Refer to \cref{sch:firstscheme}.
Refer to \cref{fig:secondfig}, \cref{fig:secondfig:a}, and \cref{fig:secondfig:b}.
Finally refer to \cref{sch:thirdscheme}, \cref{sch:thirdscheme:a}, and \cref{sch:thirdscheme:b}.

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: You're numbering schemes by chapter, but start no `\chapter`, so the chapter number is still 0. Thus the first scheme is 0.1 as expected.

Comment: @egreg Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction `\counterwithin{scheme}{chapter}` tells LaTeX that

1. the counter `scheme` is reset at each `\chapter`;
2. the representation of the counter is “chapter number”.“scheme number”; in more TeXnical terms, `\thescheme` is redefined to `\thechapter.\arabic{scheme}`.

If you have no `\chapter` command, the counter `chapter` stays at 0, so the first `scheme` caption will be numbered as 0.1, the second as 0.2 and so on.

You *need* `\chapter` to step the `chapter` counter.