# How can I edit the subref part specification?

Tags: cross-referencing

In my MWE below, I apply [leandriis's excellent recipe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571884/15622) for creating subschemes using the [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en), [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en), and [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=en) packages.

In my scheme captions, I would like to refer to the subschemes using the `\subref` command. How can I make the parts be referred to as (a) and (b), as when I refer to subfigures using `\subref`?

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  barriers/use, barriers/reset,
  use-id-as-short,
}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{charge-hshift=.5pt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{scheme}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.9em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.9em}

\AtEndPreamble{\DeclareCaptionSubType*{scheme}\counterwithin{scheme}{chapter}\renewcommand\thesubscheme{\thescheme\alph{subscheme}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{los}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefformat{subscheme}{\schemename~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listschemename}
\listofschemes

\chapter{First chapter}

% Example subfigure
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:myfigure:a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:myfigure:b}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Caption of second figure.
  Part \subref{fig:myfigure:a} and part \subref{fig:myfigure:b}.}\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

% Example subscheme
\begin{scheme}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subscheme}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{sch:myscheme:a}
  \end{subscheme}%
  \begin{subscheme}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{sch:myscheme:b}
  \end{subscheme}%
  \caption{Caption of third scheme.
  Part \subref{sch:myscheme:a} and part \subref{sch:myscheme:b}.}\label{sch:myscheme}
\end{scheme}

Refer to \cref{fig:myfigure}, \cref{fig:myfigure:a}, and \cref{fig:myfigure:b}.
Finally refer to \cref{sch:myscheme}, \cref{sch:myscheme:a}, and \cref{sch:myscheme:b}.

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: See the subcaption manual, page 10 and the caption manual page 7 (labelformat).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am using `\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}`, so I am perplexed why the figure and scheme `subref` formats look different?

Comment: Ah, inside a subfigure you should use \phantomcaption (see page 10 of subcaption manual).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```tex
\renewcommand\thesubscheme{\thescheme\alph{subscheme}}
```

to

```tex
\renewcommand\thesubscheme{\alph{subscheme}}
\renewcommand\p@subscheme{\thescheme}
```

[image]

Full example

```tex
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

%\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
%\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{acro}
%\acsetup{
%  barriers/use, barriers/reset,
%  use-id-as-short,
%}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{charge-hshift=.5pt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{scheme}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.9em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.9em}

\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{
  \DeclareCaptionSubType*{scheme}
  \counterwithin{scheme}{chapter}
  \renewcommand\thesubscheme{\alph{subscheme}}
  \renewcommand\p@subscheme{\thescheme}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{los}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\crefformat{subscheme}{\schemename~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listschemename}
\listofschemes

\chapter{First chapter}

% Example subfigure
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:myfigure:a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:myfigure:b}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{Caption of second figure.
  Part \subref{fig:myfigure:a} and part \subref{fig:myfigure:b}.}\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

% Example subscheme
\begin{scheme}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subscheme}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{sch:myscheme:a}
  \end{subscheme}%
  \begin{subscheme}{0.03\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \phantomsubcaption\label{sch:myscheme:b}
  \end{subscheme}%
  \caption{Caption of third scheme.
  Part \subref{sch:myscheme:a} and part \subref{sch:myscheme:b}.}\label{sch:myscheme}
\end{scheme}

Refer to \cref{fig:myfigure}, \cref{fig:myfigure:a}, and \cref{fig:myfigure:b}.

Finally refer to \cref{sch:myscheme}, \cref{sch:myscheme:a}, and \cref{sch:myscheme:b}.

\end{document}
```